# Confusing solution to a graph proof problem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

Here's the problem word for word: In a $G=(V,E)$ simple graph $|V|=9, |E|=25$. Show that in $G$ there's at least two vertices with degree of at least $6$.

**Given solution**

Proof by contradiction: Let's assume we only have $1$ vertex with a degree of at least $6$, while the rest have a maximum degree of $5$.

Since $|E|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n d(V_i),\quad |E|=\frac{1\cdot 6 + 8\cdot5}{2}=\frac{46}{2}=23$

However, we need $|E|=25$, therefore we must conclude that $G$ need to have at least two vertices with degree of at least $6$.

**How i tried it**

It is possible to construct a graph with the given conditions. Let one vertex have a degree of $10$, and the other eight have a maximum degree of $5$. Then $|E| = \frac{1\cdot 10+8\cdot 5}{2}=\frac{50}{2}=25$.

This way it satisfies everything the exercise states. It has the same number of edges and vertices, and it only has one vertex with a degree of at least $6$.

Either the problem is worded incorrectly, or i have a poor understanding of graphs. Which one is it?

P.S: Yes, the problem text contains the word "least" twice. I checked it.

Comment: Your solution is clearly wrong because $d(v) \le |V| - 1$, but obviously book's solution isn't complete.

Comment: Yes, after you and another replier stated this fact, it's so obvious now the degree 10 vertex is impossible. Actually nor the excercise nor the solution are not from a book, but from my teacher's "practice problems" pdf. he made, which in some is worse than if it would be from a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible to have a vertex of degree $10$ because there are only $8$ possible vertices it can be connected to. But indeed there is something wrong with the solution because it doesn't account for that possibility.

In reality he should have obtained $|E| \leq \frac{1\cdot8+8\cdot5}{2} = 24$ which still works.

If you however allow for multiple edges then you are indeed correct. You can take a vertex and add each possible edge it can have $3$ times ( so $24$ edges coming out of it), and then just connect two of the other vertices. So there will be one vertex of degree $24$, two vertices of degree $4$, and the remaining vertices of degree $3$.

Comment: Of course, if i only have 9 vertices i can't have a vertex of degree 10. This was a very amateur mistake on my part. Yes, your solution makes a lot more sense, and there aren't lingering other cases left that we haven't dealt with. Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Don't worry about it I've had way worse questions.